# The flood and living organisms

Tags: flood-of-noah

If the flood according to the book of Genesis cover the whole earth, then where are the various varieties of birds, insects and mammals from? Obviously they weren't all in the ark. 
So did God create another or what exactly?

Comment: Why do you say they obviously weren't in the ark?

Comment: The Flood was something like 4,500 years ago - plenty of time for species to diversify into what we now see around us.

Comment: Of all the animal species that we have, it's highly unlikely that even one of each kind will get the chance to get inside the ark. From its measurement according to the scriptures, not every kind of terrestrial organism could be on board.

Comment: Yes,somewhere around 4500 years ago. But then if there is diversity of organisms, then the theory of the origin of species looks true. The only difference been the time frame. That's also quite contrary to Gen. 1:21 24 and 25

Comment: @HisGrace Diversification of appearance and speciation is not seen by creationists as anything like evolution. Evolution requires an introduction of new genetic information, whereas the diversification of species is believed by creationists to have happened from the existing genetic information, as gene pools shrink as animals stop being within mating range of each other.

Comment: So then diversity could occur within the 4500years. Which of course is more than enough time. Thanks @curiousdanii. Am grateful

Answer (score 1):

Taking catkind as an example, only two mongrel cats on the ark would contain all the recessive genes necessary for all the diversity to occur which we now see. Some reckon there are 60,000 kinds. The vast majority would be small and capable of living in a small box. The ark at 300x50x30 cubits is an internal space of several x 60,000 boxes. Larger ones for birds and tiny ones for insects. Room for food and human accommodation would all be quite possible especially if we imagine baby larger animals. The authority of the Bible comes first above our imaginings.

See:

- *Biblical Creationism* by Dr. Henry Morris
- _ in six days_ edited by John F Ashton
- and all the books by *Answers in Genesis*